# Submit PySpark to Yarn cluster using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

i need to create a Java program that submit python scripts (that use PySpark) to a Yarn cluster.
Now, i saw that using SparkLauncher is the same as using a YarnClient, because it uses a Yarn Client built-in (writing my own Yarn Client is insane, i tried, too much things to handle).
So i wrote:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String SPARK_HOME = System.getProperty("SPARK_HOME");
    submit(SPARK_HOME, args);
}

static void submit(String SPARK_HOME, String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] arguments = new String[]{
            // application name
            "--name",
            "SparkPi-Python",

            "--class",
            "org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner",

            "--py-files",
            SPARK_HOME + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip,"+ SPARK_HOME +"/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",

            // Python Program
            "--primary-py-file",
            "/home/lorenzo/script.py",

            // number of executors
            "--num-executors",
            "2",

            // driver memory
            "--driver-memory",
            "512m",

            // executor memory
            "--executor-memory",
            "512m",

            // executor cores
            "--executor-cores",
            "2",

            "--queue",
            "default",

            // argument 1 to my Spark program
            "--arg",
            null,
    };
    System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
    System.out.println(SPARK_HOME);
    SparkLauncher sparkLauncher = new SparkLauncher();
    sparkLauncher.setSparkHome("/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client");
    sparkLauncher.setAppResource("/home/lorenzo/script.py");
    sparkLauncher.setMaster("yarn");
    sparkLauncher.setDeployMode("cluster");
    sparkLauncher.setVerbose(true);
    sparkLauncher.launch().waitFor();
}
```

When i run this Jar from a machine in the cluster, nothing happen... No Error, No Log, No yarn container... just nothing... if i try to put a println inside this code, obvs, it prints the println.

1. What i'm misconfiguring?
2. If i want run this JAR from a different machine, where and how should declare the IP?

Comment: What yarn address are you currently using? Have you found anything in the Spark UI like a job is running?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah that's the first problem, where should i put the address of yarn? i thought that, maybe, it's handled by sparkLauncher (contact RM, build AM ecc.) ...
Btw nothing on Spark UI

Comment: Find yarn-site.xml file, and I assume same command works on cli?

Comment: Also, you may want to try using open source projects like Livy, or Spark job launcher, depending on your needs